# Microsoft Remote Desktop spends up to a minute rearranging windows/taskbar every time I connect (dual monitor)

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Microsoft Remote Desktop is so frustrating to connect to. Every time I log on remotely, it will show the logon text and "please wait"), and then when desktop shows, it will spend up to a minute rearranging the windows and taskbar icons before it's ready to use (I have lots of applications running). Some applications will be moved to the other monitor etc.

I have changed the resolution of the server monitors to match exactly the same as the client I connect from (1920x1080 + 1080x1920), but this didn't help.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent this?

Is it possible to have Remote Desktop work without locking the local computer when connecting? E.g the display will still show the mouse movements etc.

Comment: So both machines have dual monitors? If you want to connect without locking the machine you would need an alternative to RDP/mstsc such as VNC or TeamViewer

Comment: Both have same dual monitor setup. I have tried tons of other applications, but none of them have a good multi monitor function, except TeamViewer and Microsoft Remote Desktop. But TeamViewer price is ridiculous.